# How to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 14.04

I was under the impression that upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04 was supported from all version between and including the previous LTS release (12.04). Why is it then, that update-manager (with and without -d option) will only offer to upgrade to version 13.10 from my Ubuntu 12.10 system? Even that only works when I change the updater settings from "*For long-term support versions*" to "*For any new version*."

Is it only possible to upgrade to 14.04 ***via*** 13.10?

Comment: You will probably get a cleaner system if you first backup your personal data then install 14.04 clean and finally restore your personal data from your backup.

Comment: This is a valid approach, but not preferable, due to the downtime involved. I'll be making a complete backup before attempting the upgrade, so if something goes completely wrong during the upgrade, I can always fall back on a clean install and restore from backup.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

This should upgrade your system to 14.04 from 12.04 without any problem

Comment: I don't believe this works from 12.10. It only offers me release 13.10, just as update-manager does.

Comment: @Avian00 - it works; I've just done it myself.

Comment: Can't update since I got Not Found message for all ubuntu quantal repos.
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]

Comment: @Installero Did you resolve this? I get the same error on quantal

Comment: @Phani: You get the 404 because Ubuntu has removed Quantal from its normal mirrors. DigitalOcean still has a mirror of Quantal at http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu-old. Replace the URLs in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` with this and you will be able to update Quantal to the last packages released.

Comment: FYI if `do-release-upgrade` results in `command not found` you need to `apt-get install update-manager-core`