# Trying to upgrade from 12.10 to 14.04 and not having any luck...404 error occurs

Tags: dual-boot, 12.10, upgrade, updates, update-manager

This is a long winded question so bear with me!

I am trying to upgrade my 12.10 Quental Ubuntu to the 14.04 version. This has led to a problem within my system not being able to update. For information, this build of Ubuntu does a dual-boot with my Windows 7 package.

I initially tried to find the update manager on my system which has dissapeared. I then searched on Google and came to this page:

[How to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453596/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-12-10-to-14-04)

When typing in sudo apt-get update, it hits 18% and says, "Waiting for headers."

A couple of errors occur. The last two lines of the error log state:

"W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/raring/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead."

I have checked online and found this page in answer to this problem:

[How can I fix a 404 Error when using a PPA or updating my package lists?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-updating-packages)

During the main answer it suggests to type these three lines into the command line:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/packagefixes

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install banish404

After I run sudo banish404, I still get the same error message.

My final aim is to just update Ubuntu to 14.04 in my Dual boot machine. My fear is if I download an ISO and try to run it from booting my machine, it will either wipe everything, (and there is a lot of stuff within my Windows account!) or provide a triple boot scenario whereby I choose between Windows, Ubuntu 12.10 and Ubuntu 14.04.

My experience is very limited with Linux and the command line, (did a short course a couple of years ago with my uni.) Although it has increased a lot in the last two days, (I have created to a Kali Linux virtual machine and a SIFT forensics virtual machine, both in virtual box on my windows account.)

Any help?

Comment: See also [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release) and [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: I followed the instructions from the 404 error page via the second link. this worked for me really well, and then allowed me to update from 13.04 to 13.10, then 13.10 to 14.04. That had its own error which was also resolved via another askubuntu thread!

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest solutions is to boot a liveUSB/DVD, choose install Ubuntu, then "Something else" and choose the actual Ubuntu partition as the root (/) partition and select it for formatting.

Backup your important files and your home folder first.

Ubuntu 14.04 will replace 12.10. You will have to reinstall any extra software you had installed.

Comment: thanks for your response. I ended up going through each version before getting to 14.04 as opposed to your answer, which I have only just seen. as an extra question, as I'm still getting my head around partitions, on my dual boot machine, would the install ubuntu start-up screens actually state that there was another parition with windows and ubuntu in it? I only ask as I recently uploaded Ubuntu server to another machine which when going through it, never showed me that there was another partition on it, (it was a windows machine beforehand.)

Comment: It did mention before deleting the disk that there was another Master Boot Record (MBR) there, (I think) but didn't give me the option to dual boot with that other operating system.