# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates

I have run sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade

I then ran sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  The output of this produced a long list headed "the following security updates require Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-infra' enabled... and concluded "0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.

I then ran sudo do-release-upgrade with the result "Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading"

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 will be out of support next April so you're basically wasting your time. Do your backups and install fresh 22.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upgrading to a no longer supported version](https://askubuntu.com/questions/518874/upgrading-to-a-no-longer-supported-version)

Comment: the issue is that you need Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-infra' enabled in order to update some packages, and you need to update the packages in order to do a release upgrade. You have a few options: 1. get Ubuntu Pro 2. remove the packages in question 3. backup and install a new version of Ubuntu from scratch

Comment: You *may* need to apply all upgrades before upgrading as the message says; that may now require an ESM/UA connection before it can be done.  It will depend on what package(s) exist on your system (*plus where you are in the world, as certificates may have expired where you are & need upgrading which requires ESM now for 16.04*).  16.04 told you 2016-April, so you knew you had 5 years before ESM was required (ie. till 2021-April for EOSS) so you were warned (*all release notes gave the support duration*)

Comment: Technically 18.04 is still supported, so this question **is** about upgrading to a supported version. and **Is on-Topic**. I vote to keep open.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who has provided their answers to this questions.  On balance it seems that backing up data and installing a new version is the most straight forward solution.  
It is clearly disappinting that upgrading (my scheduled upgrade was disrupted by covid) to a supported version seems to be either very complicated or involves paying for extra services, so much for "Ubuuntu is free and always will be"

Comment: @Patrick: Who asked you to pay extra for services? Re ESM please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331483/how-to-get-extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04.